# Special case of double integral where the upper bond of the inner integral is the integration variable of the out integral

Tags: calculus, integration

This is regarding a special type of double integral looking like the following:

$$\int_0^T  \exp\left(\int_0^\color{red}{t} f(s)\, ds\right) \,\color{red}{dt}. $$

Time being the integration variable here, one can think of $T$ as entire duration which sets the boundary of the outer integral, and the inner integral integrates from $0$ to each discrete time point $t$, and take the exponential of it. Here, the upper bond of the inner integral is the integration variable of the outer integral.

I suspect the expression can be simply to:

$$ \exp\left(\int_0^T f(t)\, dt\right). $$

but I'm not sure if this is correct. Can anyone enlighten me with the missing links in between and correct me if my suspicion is wrong.

Comment: Yeah your suspicion is wrong. The inner integral is a function of $t$, and hence the outer integral will be different from the last one you wrote

Comment: @Dude, any idea what should it be?

Comment: I’m not sure if it can be simplified at all, unless you know $f(s)$.

Answer (score -1):

You can look at it as

$$\int\limits_{0}^{T}e^{\int\limits_{0}^{t}f(s) \mathrm{d}s} \mathrm{d}t$$
for f$(s) = -\frac{s}{2}$, for example, you obtain well known
$$\int\limits_{0}^{T}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: I don't think that this addresses the question.  Your first line is just the integral in the question, formatted slightly differently.  The second line gives an example, but gives no details and is therefore relatively unenlightening.  Neither part of this answer addresses the core issue of the question.

Comment: @Xander Henderson. First line answers wrong suspicion  denominated in question. It is not "just integral in the question", but same in different form, which clears its functional idea. Second show example as way to famous Gaussian distribution. As to "core issue" do you think it is possible only your view? I count, if this is interesting for you, that rather should be discussion and attempt to come to mutual understanding, then down voting and declaring own view as unique point of enlightening. May be yo can give your variant of answer at least?